# File name too long in android glide library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-glide

I have image name (String) which was base64 decoded. But when i want to set that image into circleImageView (library) using Glide, some random data is being printed in LOG and says (file name too long).

My question is - How can we set too long file name images using Glide (OR) do we have any alternative library to load these type of images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT))
    .asBitmap()
    .into(circleImageView);
```

Comment: no explanation of code provided. consider writing some comments for your code